# counter re-indexing on row delete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic form which inserts new rows onto the page.  Each row will generate new `id` (project1, project2, project3 based on the counter value). When I delete a row, I set my counter to decrease.

Say I have 4 dynamically generated rows and I delete row 3. Now, when I add a new row, I end up with 2x `id` with project4. Is there an easy way of simply re-indexing the rows, so if row 3 is deleted, then 4 becomes 3 etc. Instead of using my current counter method? Would I need to store each row as an array?

I may be completely over complicating things by doing it my current way.

```js
  jQuery('a.pluslink').click(function(event) {
  var counter = 1;

    event.preventDefault();

    var newRow = jQuery(
      '<tr><td><input class="form-control full-width autocomplete" id="project' + counter +
      '"  type="text"></td>' +
      '<td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
      '"/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"/><td>' +
      '<input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '/></td></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +

      '"/></td><td><input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0"' +
      '/></td>' + '<td><a href="#" class="minuslink">Delete</a></td></tr>');

    $('#project' + counter, newRow);

    jQuery('table.tablesubmit tr:last').before(newRow);

    counter++;
  });

  $("table.tablesubmit").on('click', '.minuslink', function(e) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().parent().remove();

    counter--;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tablesubmit">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="30%">Project name</th>
      <th width="10%">Mon</th>
      <th width="10%">Tue</th>
      <th width="10%">Wed</th>
      <th width="10%">Thur</th>
      <th width="10%">Fri</th>
      <th width="10%">Sat</th>
      <th width="10%">Sun</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="project" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1.25">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="5.5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="" class="minuslink">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold" width="25%">
        <a>Total Time:</a>
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.25" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="8" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7.5" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="7" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <input class="form-control full-width" id="full-name-f1" type="text" value="0" style="background-color:#DEE0E2;">
      </td>
      <td>37.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<a href="#" class="pluslink">Add new project</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run over each line with `$().each()`, and re-number them.
But the real question is actually : Why do you change your counter ? I would actually work on the server-side code that processes the data so it works even if you have holes.
For exemple, in php :

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
{
  if(strpos($key,"project")==0)
  {
    // process whole row
    // You can even use a sub-string to get the counter and call the other inputs you have on the same row this way
  }
}
```

If you must have it on the client side, I would go about it like this :

```
jQuery('a.pluslink').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var counter=0;
  jQuery('table.tablesubmit tr').each ( function (i) {
    var input=$(this).find('input[name^="project"]');
    if(input.length>0) counter++;
    input.attr('id','project'+counter);
  });
  counter++;
  var newRow = jQuery(
    //no changes there
  );
  jQuery('table.tablesubmit tr:last').before(newRow);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, we are looking at ways of doing it within the back-end. We need the dynamically added rows to have unique IDs so this is the way I've tried first.

Comment: There are cases where you will need a unique ID in the front end, yes. In that case, try running over each row with `jQuery().each()` whenever you add a new row and resetting the counter for each.

Comment: Appreciate the help, though I'm not sure where to start with this.

Comment: Edited answer to add client-side solution

Comment: Running out of ideas here... Maybe try setting up a jsfiddle, so I can look at the whole code... I won't be able to look at it until late tomorrow, but maybe other people get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to base the table on an array (which you can update more easily) and completely rewrite the table every time you delete a value from the array (NOTE the use of **index** to change the numbers in the ids for the inputs):

```js
table_array = [
  {
    cell_1_value:"cell 1 row 1",
  },
  {
    cell_1_value:"cell 1 row 2",
  },
];
function write_table_from_array(this_array){
  table_html = '<table>';
  this_array.forEach(function(row,index){
    table_html += "<tr><td><input id='input_row"+index+"'>"+row.cell_1_value+"<input class='delete_button' id='delete_"+index+"' type='button' value='delete'></td></tr>";
  });
  table_html += '</table>';
  document.getElementById("table_div").innerHTML = table_html;
  
  //keep this in function
  $(".delete_button").on("click",function(){
    row_to_delete = this.id.replace("delete_","");
    table_array.splice(row_to_delete,1);
    write_table_from_array(table_array);
  });
}
write_table_from_array(table_array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```